# Looking To Set An int Answer To The Form Of A Currency

Tags: java, decimal, calculator, currency

I am coding my first app in java, it is a simple Tip Calculator. The problem I am having is I am having a hard time trying to figure out how I can get my final answer to come back properly formatted in US currency form ($##.##) Whenever I would try something like setting up a currency string in my code it would say it is being ignored by my strings and this was not doing anything. Here is my main Java code:

```
    package com.rockdrummer.calculating.calculating;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.InputFilter;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import java.util.Locale;


    public class MainScreen extends Activity {
    Button ten, fifteen, twenty;
    TextView tip;
    EditText bill_amount;
    double a;
    double b;
    double af;
    double bf;
    double ac;
    double bc;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
    initControls();
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);


    }

    protected void initControls() {
    ten = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTen);
    fifteen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bFifteen);
    twenty = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTwenty);
    tip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tip);
    bill_amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bill);

    tip.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{
            new InputFilter.LengthFilter(20)});


    ten.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View ten) {
            try {
                calculate();
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    fifteen.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View fifteen) {
            try {
                calculate_f();
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    twenty.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View twenty) {
            try {
                calculate_t();
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    }

    private void calculate() {
    a = Double.parseDouble(bill_amount.getText().toString());
    b = a * 0.1;
    tip.setText("You Should Tip $" + Double.toString(b));
    }

    private void calculate_f() {
    af = Double.parseDouble(bill_amount.getText().toString());
    bf = af * 0.15;
    tip.setText("You Should Tip $" + Double.toString(bf));
    }

    private void calculate_t() {
    ac = Double.parseDouble(bill_amount.getText().toString());
    bc = ac * 0.20;
    tip.setText("You Should Tip $" + Double.toString(bc));
    }

    }
```

I appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

With doubles, you are going to need to apply a rounding mode, to avoid any inconsistent bits. You will get some strange results if you don't. The easiest method I've found is using the Java class BigInteger:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigInteger.html
Then use DecimalFormat:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html